# How to call a cross-domain REST service from a sharepoint-hosted app using current Identity (Azure AD/ADFS)?

Tags: rest, azure, office365-apps, adal

How to call an AzureAD-secured cross-domain REST service from a sharepoint-hosted app using current Identity ?
Actually, is it possible ?
If not, does anyone can give me a good alternative.

I have already implemented a similar scenario from an AzureAD-secured web site (Pure HTML/JS) using ADAL JS to call a WebAPI service with success using ADAL JS examples.